# Conditionally install x64 drivers with Inno Setup

Tags: windows-installer, inno-setup, bootstrapping

I am attempting to use Inno Setup to bootstrap a WiX generated .msi file with all required prerequisites.

For the most part this is working quite well, but I cannot locate any information to conditionally install and run a prerequisite installer based on x86/x64, like I can in Windows Installer.

Anybody have any luck with this?  I am trying to avoid having a separate x64 installer just because of a single driver.  The application I am bootstrapping runs in x86 and relies on WOW for x64 support.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the "64BitThreeArch.iss" sample in $(InnoSetup)/Examples, it installs one of three different executables, depending on the architecture the installation runs on. You can use similar checks for all your script sections.